# I can't send byte array as parameter in REST service ?  ( code attached ) 

Tags: wcf

I'm using WCF to create some REST service. 
One of the Rest Service method need to get byte array as parameter ( picture as byte array ) and return some object. 
I run this service using IIS. 
But this is not working.

The code that i wrote :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPicService
{
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "GetPicReport/{imageName}")]
    Report GetPicReport( string imageName, Stream image );

}

[ServiceBehavior( AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any )]
public class PicService: IPicService
{
    public Report GetPicReport( string imageName, Stream image )
    {
        return new Report ();
    }
}
```

I checking this code using explorer - but i get an error about missing parameter ( the image stream )

How can i test it ? 
I can't use the WCF Test Client - so i wrote simple application that create http call - and this method return error 404 ( server not found )

Comment: You said you're passing the parameter as a byte array, but your code uses Stream, not byte[].

Comment: in first - i send byte array and the second parameter was byte array. But i change it to be Stream and still does not work from tesing application that i wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request != null)
        {
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.Method = method;
        }

        //var objContent = HttpContentExtensions.CreateDataContract(requestBody);
        if(method == "POST" && requestBody != null)
        {
            //byte[] requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingXmlSer(requestBody, "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLService");
            byte[] requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingDataContractSer(requestBody);
            request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);
            //request.Timeout = 60000;
        }

        if (request != null)
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                    responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx) shows how to implement a service just like yours, along with a test client (using `HttpWebRequest`). Another thing you can do is to enable tracing at the server, it may tell you why the request is being rejected.